# Ошибка извлечения из файла Python 3.5 (не удалось определить имя)

Tags: python-3.5, импорт

Как правильно извлечь из файла всё, без ошибки. Вот пример.

```
def __code_import__():
    from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
    init()
    #DEFAULT_COLOR
    FW = Fore.WHITE
    FG = Fore.GREEN
    FC = Fore.CYAN
    FB = Fore.BLUE
    FR = Fore.RED
    FM = Fore.MAGENTA
    FY = Fore.YELLOW
    FBB = Fore.BLACK
    #LIGHT_COLOR
    FLW = Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX
    FLG = Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX
    FLC = Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX
    FLB = Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX
    FLR = Fore.LIGHTRED_EX
    FLM = Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX
    FLY = Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX
    FLBB = Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX
    #BACKGROUND_DEFAULT_COLOR
    BW = Back.WHITE
    BG = Back.GREEN
    BC = Back.CYAN
    BB = Back.BLUE
    BR = Back.RED
    BM = Back.MAGENTA
    BY = Back.YELLOW
    BBL = Back.BLACK
    #BACKGROUND_LIGHT_COLOR
    BLW = Back.LIGHTWHITE_EX
    BLG = Back.LIGHTGREEN_EX
    BLC = Back.LIGHTCYAN_EX
    BLB = Back.LIGHTBLUE_EX
    BLR = Back.LIGHTRED_EX
    BLM = Back.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX
    BLY = Back.LIGHTYELLOW_EX
    BLBL = Back.LIGHTBLACK_EX
    #STYLE
    SRA = Style.RESET_ALL
    SD = Style.DIM
    SB = Style.BRIGHT
```

Когда извлекаю простым импортом возникает ошибка что имя FLC не удалось определить!

Comment: почему вы думаете, что локальные переменные должны быть доступны через "простой импорт". Приведите явно минимальный пример кода, который вы ожидали что должен работать.

Answer (score 0):

Данная переменная доступна лишь внутри функции "__code_import__".

Не уверен, что это корректно, но я сделал бы так.

```
# your_module source
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

FW = Fore.WHITE
# ------- Other colors --------
SB = Style.BRIGHT


def __import__():
    init()

# your program source
from your_module import *

print(FLC)
```

**UPD**
А ещё лучше через класс:

```
class MyColors(object):
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

    self.FW = Fore.WHITE
    # ------- Other colors --------
    self.SB = Style.BRIGHT

def __import__():
    from colorama import init

    init()
```

А вызывать, вот так:

```
from my_module import MyColors

print(MyColors.SB + "string with color")
```